# Java + база данных. С чего начать?

Tags: java, mysql

В универе начали проходить MySQL и дали задание написать свою базу данных и графический интерфейс к ней. Базу данный, то я слеплю, а вот как к этому добавить графический интерфейс   не очень представляю. Для создания всего этого разрешили пользоваться любыми средствами и я решил выбрать java и MySQL. Так вот с чего начать? Посоветуйте, пожалуйста.

Comment: вау, а что за вуз?

Comment: обычно любой, где есть курс по СУБД

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Почитать про Swing по части создания UI и про JDBC, как средство работы с БД.

Answer (score 0):

Spring roo. Он позвовляет генерировать ui исходя из схемы бд. Очень быстро и можно примерно посмотреть как это обычно делается в спринге.